# iOS 6.0 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation not calling

Tags: ios

I am having a Universal Project in iOS and that was working fine in all of the orientation but in iOS 6.0

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

Method is not calling any more.

Even the other methods are not working.

Suggest me some fast solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This solved it for me. However, I shouldn't have had to do that as far as the iOS 6 release notes say:

> "For compatibility, view controllers that still implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method do not get the new autorotation behaviors. (In other words, they do not fall back to using the app, app delegate, or Info.plist file to determine the supported orientations.)".

[iOS 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` instead.
Read the Apple Documentation, or watch Sessions from 2012 WWDC.

Comment: I wanted to set the frames of objects but none of the methods are calling when get oriented

Comment: Actually, iOS 6 release notes read: "For compatibility, view controllers that still implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method do not get the new autorotation behaviors. (In other words, they do not fall back to using the app, app delegate, or Info.plist file to determine the supported orientations.)". I am also experiencing issues of backwards compatibility.